# How the change the date format when using the Calendar field type?

Tags: joomla-3.x

In the extension I have used a date field, with the Field Type of Calendar (this uses the Joomla Date selector).

However, the date is being formatted to YYYY-MM-DD.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to change it to exactly?

Comment: I want to change it to DD-MM-YYYY

Answer (score 1):

To change the way the date is formatted, you simply ass the `format` attribute to the field. As you want to change it to `DD-MM-YY`, you can use the following:

```
<field 
    name="calendar"
    type="calendar" 
    label="Select Date"
    default="21-11-2014"
    format="%d-%m-%Y"
/>
```

For more information on the calendar field type, please have a look at the following:

http://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried this previously, but when saving from the component, the date is changed to 0000-00-00 in the component.

Comment: @RustyJoomla - Are you using Joomla 3.3.6?

Comment: Yes, Joomla 3.3.6

Comment: Hmm odd. According to the docs, the format defines the way it's stored so it should work. I'll have a quick check

Comment: I've just tested this on a random module. Added the above code to the module's XML file, selected a date from the calendar, saved it, then echoed the value in the default.php and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, it's not working in the code which component-creator is outputting unfortunately. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @RustyJoomla did you fix this issue ? How did you fixed that ?

Comment: It's not fixed unfortunately